# FedEx free shipping by minimum weight

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, free-shipping, fedex, product-weight

I'm trying to set up my shipping rates to be free for products over 150lbs and calculate the shipping rates for products that are below 150lbs - **per product**, not on the order total.

> **Scenario:** I have `product 1` that weighs `25lbs` in my cart: *Calculate the shipping rate with FedEx, for example, $25.*
>
> **Scenario:** I have `product 2` that weighs `200lbs` in my cart: *Give free shipping.*
>
> **Scenario:** I have both `product 1` (`25lbs`) and `product 2` (`200lbs`) in my cart: *Calculate the shipping rate with FedEx for
> product 1 ($25) and give free shipping for product 2.*

The problem is that both the free shipping method and the 'Enable free shipping' option in the FedEx shipping setting offer free shipping by **order** price only, how can do the same with **product weight**?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `shopping cart price rule` with no coupon code to automatically apply in the cart when certain criteria are met.

Create a new rule

In the `Rule Information` tab, set `no coupon` in the `coupon` field.

In the `Conditions` tab, use `if ALL of these conditions are TRUE` where `Total Weight equals or greater than 150`

In the `Actions` tab, set `Apply to Shipping Amount` as `YES` and `Free Shipping` to `For Shipment with Matching Items`

Give it a label if you want and any other configurations are at your discretion.

Save the rule and run a test, you should see the label show up in the cart, and when you request a shipping quote, all options should be marked as $0.00

This is not Shipping Method specific, it applies to all available shipping methods. It may not work for you if you have other options available.

Comment: This is a cool workaround but only works for the cart total weight, I need a per product solution

Comment: Can you help to break this down into more detailed information? Are you planning to only charge shipping on products under 150lbs (each), and give free shipping for products over 150lbs (each)? Do all items ship separately?

Comment: I am planning to only charge shipping on products under 150lbs (each) and give free shipping on products over 150lbs (each), Items over 150lbs will ship separately.

Comment: Have you tried setting products with weight of 150lbs or more to 0 in it's configuration so it doesn't skew the calculated shipping rates from FedEx? Keep both "free shippings" options disabled and it should only calculate shipping cost based on available weights. Otherwise the extensions I'm seeing available are flat cost shipping-per-product and don't allow for use of auto-calculated shipping costs by weight (ie FedEx, etc..)

Comment: Tried doing so, but it gives me an error that the shipping method is not available. ps. you don't need to set the weight to 0 in order to skew the calculated shipping rates, I got the same result by setting the max weight in the FedEx settings to 150lbs

Comment: Do you have products that weigh exactly 150, if so why not max FedEx at 149lb?

Comment: I added case scenarios to the question, hope this will help you understand my question. Thank You.